# Speech Recognition Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, speech-recognition, mozilla

I have created a Speech Recognition site following the API:  https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/ . The site works in Chrome but not in Safari.

This makes sense: Based on the browser support details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API#browser_support, (speech to text is currently limited to Chrome for Desktop and Android.)

But doesn’t make sense based on: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#browser_compatibility%C2%A0)  The last link, claims there is support.

**I am confused, does Safari offer support or not?**

The error I get from Safari is: Speech recognition error detected: service-not-allowed

What does this error mean?

**service-not-allowed**

The user agent disallowed the requested speech recognition service, either because the user agent doesn't support it or because of reasons of security, privacy or user preference. In this case it would allow another more suitable speech recognition service to be used instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent/error

I tried giving explicit permission for the mic, in the Safari settings and in my computer settings. Didn’t work. I don’t know how to give explicit permission to safari for speech recognition. It should ask for permission, but it doesn’t.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed to get speech recognition to work on Safari?

This is the code:

````
var recognition = new speechRecognition()

var textBox = $("#textbox")

var instructions = $("#instructions")

var cont = ''

recognition.continuous = true

// Recognition started

recognition.onstart = function () {
    instructions.text("Voice recognition is on")
}

recognition.onspeechend = function () {
    instructions.text("No speech detected")
}

recognition.onerror = function (event) {
    instructions.text('Speech recognition error detected: ' + event.error)
}

recognition.onresult = function (event) {
    var current =  event.resultIndex;
    var transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;

    cont += transcript

    textBox.val(cont)
}

$("#start-btn").click(function (event) {
    if(cont.length){
        cont += ''
    }
    recognition.start()
})``` 

I created this based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwB6RqqCmXc
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. For Safari, users need to enable dictation for speech to text to work.
Details can be found here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225298

Comment: Nice find. This is still required as as of Oct 2021. Safari is the IE?

Comment: I did jump through all these (Siri enabled, allow mic to site) ... but my `http://localhost:8888` still gives `error: "service-not-allowed"` ... for Chrome I suspect **https://** is needed for non localhost. Unfortunately https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speech-color-changer/ does not work on Safari

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you have an SSL certificate set up on the site? Sometimes the browser might block access to the microphone if it is not on a secure connection.

Now if this is a local site you can use a Self-Signed SSL certificate as a workaround if this isn't published.

Comment: I confirm that for some configs, the app needs to be served from https rather than http.